# Where can I find datasets suitable for an undergraduate research project?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, research

I have tried Kaggle but couldn’t find anything suitable. Basically I want to do a machine learning or deep learning project. Ideally it would have something to do with computer forensics or security. I have found a good dataset [here](https://www.unb.ca/cic/datasets/ddos-2019.html).
But its very large and hard on my system I.e. a MacBook with i5 processor and 8 G/bs of RAM. I am also considering doing Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) but I can’t seem to find any datasets anywhere other than what’s in the standard built in library's of Tensorflow 2 etc. Any help would be appreciated. Also with the link I gave above I can only get the datasets from them if I look up the paper on IEEE I can only get the paper not the code used is there away to view the original authors code in their paper they stated they used Machine Learning to predict values I was thinking I could use deep learning in my version but id like to review their work first.